# Repercussions of Reassigning Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates

I'm looking to find out what the effects are (if any) of assigning a delegate multiple times? Is it bad practice to assign a delegate inside viewWillAppear considering I do not assign the delegate to another viewController?

It is just a simple custom delegate for one of my classes. I need the delegate in one view of my tabBar, but not in the other. And since I've been assigning it in viewWillAppear, and viewWillAppear gets called every time you change tabs, I was just wondering if there were some unwanted effects.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context to be sure but in general, you can safely assign a delegate all you want. But there is no way to be sure with such little info about your use.

Comment: Okay thank you for the response. Please check my edit and let me know if you still feel the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in the case you describe there should be no problem. But it depends on what your code does when the delegate is assigned. If it's a simple property assignment with no custom implementation of the 'setter' method for the property, then you have no issue. But if you wrote your own 'setter' method for the property and the implementation performs other actions, then it is possible that those other actions could be an issue.

Either way, you may wish to consider moving the assignment to the `viewDidLoad` method. As if iOS 6 this will only be called once. Under iOS 5 or earlier it could be called more than once but `viewDidUnload` will be called as well in such cases.